# React/Redux wait for store to update

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am currently building my first app using react and redux. I have built some filters and when the user selects a filter, it will update the store with the new filter value, and then request the new results.

The store is being updated with the new filter value, but the fetch request is happening before the store has finished updating and so returns the incorrect value.

How can i wait for the store to update before making the fetch request?

Below is my code...

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        dataFilter: state.dataFilter
    }
};

class Filters extends Component {
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
}

handleChange(value, dispatcher){
    dispatcher(value.props["data-attr"]);

    this.props.resultsFetchData('/api/deals/?data=' + this.props.dataFilter);
}

render() {
    const dataFilters = {
        0: <span data-attr="0">Any</span>,
        20: <span data-attr="1">1GB+</span>,
        40: <span data-attr="2">2GB+</span>,
        60: <span data-attr="5">5GB+</span>,
        80: <span data-attr="10">10GB+</span>,
        100: <span data-attr="99.99">Unltd</span>
    };

    return (
        <div className="filters">
            <div className="row">
                <div className="col-sm-4 filters--slider">
                    <Slider
                        min={0}
                        marks={dataFilters}
                        step={null}
                        defaultValue={this.props.dataFilter}
                        onChange={e => {this.handleChange(dataFilters[e], this.props.setDataFilter)}} />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        );
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {setDataFilter, resultsFetchData})(Filters)

Filters.propTypes = {
dataFilter: PropTypes.string
}
```

Comment: You can add a check in mapStateToProps: `dataFilter: state && state.dataFilter ? state.dataFilter || anyDefaultValue`. Or in the 
 `handleChange()`, you can add an if statement to check if the prop is valid or not.

Comment: Or you can move the fetch call into the componentWillReceiveProps method

Comment: I tried moving the fetch into the componentWillReceiveProps but then it just constantly makes the API call until it errors from too many connections?

Answer (score 1):

Using componentWillReceiveProps worked as a solution for me...

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
    if(nextProps.dataFilter !== this.props.dataFilter){
        this.props.resultsFetchData('/api/deals/?data=' + nextProps.dataFilter);
    }
}

handleChange(value, dispatcher){
    dispatcher(value.props["data-attr"]);
}
```